# Busca retorna dados iguais

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou fazendo um sistema de busca aonde tem alguns campos (condições) para pesquisar e achar os resultados. Esses campos nenhum é obrigatório, caso a pessoa digite algo ele irá achar pelos dados digitados, caso a pessoa não digite, o sistema buscará todos os dados do banco. O problema é que eu uso o seguinte código:

```
<?php
       $noiva_nome = @$_POST['noiva_nome'];
       $noivo_nome = @$_POST['noivo_nome'];

       $noiva_pai  = @$_POST['noiva_pai'];
       $noiva_mae  = @$_POST['noiva_mae'];

       $noivo_pai  = @$_POST['noivo_pai'];
       $noivo_mae  = @$_POST['noivo_mae'];

       $data       = @$_POST['ano']."-".@$_POST['mes']."-".@$_POST['dia'];

       $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noivos WHERE noiva_nome LIKE '%$noiva_nome%' OR noivo_nome LIKE '%$noivo_nome%' OR noiva_mae LIKE '%$noiva_mae%' OR noiva_pai LIKE '%$noiva_pai%' OR noivo_mae LIKE '%$noivo_mae%' OR noivo_pai LIKE '%$noivo_pai%' OR data LIKE '%$data%'");
```

Esse código, caso o usuário não digite nada nos inputs ele irá fazer uma pesquisa tipo assim `noiva_nome LIKE '%%' , ou seja, vazio e mesmo assim ele irá retornar o resultado pois o PHP encontra resultados. O erro é que as vezes o usuário até digita o nome da noiva por exemplo, só que os outros campos estão vazios, então ele retorna o resultado que tem o nome da noiva mas também retorna os outros resultados nada a ver também, por causa dos inputs em branco. Tem alguma forma de fazer ele buscar primeiro pelos resultados digitados pelo usuário e ignorar os vazios?

Comment: E utilizares o AND em vez do OR? Talvez te resolva o problema

Comment: Mas fazendo isso ele não vai obrigar a procurar algo que contenha resultados? Ou seja, só retornar se conter o nome da noiva e os resultados em branco?

Comment: Não seria melhor injetar na query apenas se houver algum valor referente ao campo?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli sim, não é isso que queres? "O erro é que as vezes o usuário até digita o nome da noiva por exemplo, só que os outros campos estão vazios, então ele retorna o resultado que tem o nome da noiva mas também retorna os outros resultados nada a ver também", foi o que entendi da tua descrição

Comment: Eu preciso que ele busque o que o usuário digitou. O Problema é que não existe filtro para ver quais campos o usuário digitou, então eu coloquei todas as colunas do MySQL para ele buscar e se o usuário preencher só um input que é uma coluna do banco, ele acha o resultado, mas também imprime outros pois as outras colunas (inputs) não foram preenchidos então ficaram como `%%`

Comment: Sugiro independente do problema da pergunta, a migração para `mysqli`. Leitura recomendada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A melhor opção para o seu caso é construir a sua *query* de forma mais inteligente:

```
<?php

$camposFormulario = array(
    'noiva_nome',
    'noivo_nome',
    'noiva_pai',
    'noiva_mae',
    'noivo_pai',
    'noivo_mae',
    'data'
);

$camposBusca = array();

// Loop com os campos do fomulário, para popular a query
foreach ($camposFormulario as $campo)
{
    // O campo formuário está vazio?
    if (isset($_POST[$campo])){
        // campo LIKE '%valorCampo%'
        $valor = mysql_escape_string($_POST[$campo]);
        $camposBusca[$campo] = "$campo LIKE '%{$valor}%'";
    }
}

// Query inicial
$query = 'SELECT * FROM noivos';

// Injeta na query os campos pesquisados se existir 
if (!empty($camposBusca)){
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $camposBusca);
}

echo $query;
```

Acho interessante mudar seu formulário e enviar a data completa.

Isso irá evitar casos onde o usuário deixa de preencher o ano por exemplo, causando uma pesquisa de data inválida.

> -09-15 , --15 , 2014-03-

Answer (score 4):

A [resposta do @gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32529/70) é muito bem elaborada e já recebeu meu +1, só estou complementando com uma versão mais básica, para outros leitores com problema similar, que pode ser interessante para condições menos regulares que as da pergunta original:

```
<?php
   $nome = $_POST['nome']; // Sanitize tudo para evitar injection!
   $data = $_POST['data'];
   //... repita para cada campo ...

   $condicoes = array();
   if( !empty( $nome ) ) $condicoes[] = "nome LIKE '$nome'";
   if( !empty( $data ) ) $condicoes[] = "DATE_FORMAT(data,...) = '$data'";
   //... repita e ajuste cada condição para cada campo ...

   $query = 'SELECT * FROM tabela'; // Esta query deve ser funcional mesmo sem where
   if( !empty($condicoes) ) $query .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $condicoes );

   echo $query; // aqui é só mandar pro DB
```