# Como criar uma Query dinâmica em php

Tags: php, mysql

Olá gostaria da ajuda de vocês , estou criando um formulário com php e mysql , nesse formulário tem a tela de requisição , tipo tem os campos para ser preenchidos com o `month` e nome , no monte tem o mês e ano e no nome a pessoa digita o nome ou o numero da carteirinha .

Mas ai que vem o problema que estou enfrentando , quando a pessoa digita o mês vem o mês que ela solicitou , mas quando não digita vem todos os dados de todos os meses , até ai tá certo pois quero que venha assim , mas quero que no campo nome fique assim também , quando digita o nome venha só o nome e quando não digitar venha tudo , tem como vocês me ajudarem .

Ai está a parte da `Query` . o `$datcadastro` é a data essa tá certa mas o `$nomfuncionario` só retorna quando digita , quero que quando não digitar nada venha tudo e quando digitar  o nome só venha o nome digitado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function RetornaRelatorios($datcadastro,$nomfuncionario)
{

    if(!empty($datcadastro)&& !empty($nomfuncionario)){
        $WHERE = "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.datcadastro,'%Y-%m') = '$datcadastro' AND (a.nomfuncionario) = '$nomfuncionario' ";


    }else{
        $WHERE = "";


    }

    $this->sql = "SELECT 
                date_format(a.datcadastro,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as datcadastro,
                a.beneficiario,
                a.intercambio,
                a.procedimento,
                date_format(a.datprocedimento,'%d/%m/%Y') as datprocedimento,
                a.numguia,
                a.retrospectivo,
                a.presencial,
                a.nomfuncionario,
                a.audmedico,
                a.hospital
                    FROM opme.auditoria a
                        $WHERE

                ;";
}
```

Comment: Pra mim, é duplicata dessa: [Busca retorna dados iguais](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32521/busca-retorna-dados-iguais) e a solução realmente está bem simples lá, mas como você quer insistir em fazer do seu jeito, deixo por conta da comunidade responder e/ou decidir se é duplicata ou não. Só espero que não comece a aparecer resposta que já tem na outra, pq ai vira bagunça.

Comment: @Bacco Fiz da sua forma só uma coisa que não entendo o que eu tenho que colocar dentro do $WHERE = array();

Comment: Nao é pra por nada, você só deveria mexer nestas linhas: `if( !empty( $nome ) ) $condicoes[] = "nome LIKE '$nome'";` e repetir pra todos os campos. Cada linha dessas é para um campo separado. O resto não precisa mexer, só acertar a $query com o nome da tabela.

Comment: Algo mais ou menos assim: http://pastebin.com/0K3FugYM

Comment: @Bacco valeu  está funcionando .

Comment: tente entender a lógica, dá pra fazer coisas bem legais se você entender o funcionamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece pelo operador de busca que você esta utilizando, o igual "=" faz uma busca pelo conteúdo exato do input, use o like com '%':

```
campoTabela like '%$variavel%'
```

Dessa forma o sistema irá efetuar buscas relativas ao conteúdo digitado, inclusive trazer todos os clientes ao deixar o campo vazio.

Comment: @Bacco olá no datcadastro está certo falta só para numfuncionario . a única coisa que queria mudar é essa parte do código $WHERE = "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.datcadastro,'%Y-%m')  = '$datcadastro'
 " AND  a.nomfuncionario = '$nomfuncionario'" ; tipo quando um estiver preenchido e o outro não trazer os resultados .

Comment: @Bacco  vi lá e deixei a query assim $WHERE = "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.datcadastro,'%Y-%m') = '$datcadastro' AND (a.nomfuncionario) LIKE '%$nomfuncionario%' ";

Comment: @Bacco mudei o que tinha que mudar mais não retorna o esperado , tem alguma forma de eu mudar apenas alguma coisa nessa linha para que retorne o esperado ? $WHERE = "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.datcadastro,'%Y-%m') = '$datcadastro' AND (a.nomfuncionario) = '$nomfuncionario' "; se tiver ficaria muito grato

Comment: @Bacco Fiz dessa forma   $WHERE = array();
   if( !empty( $nomfuncionario ) ) $WHERE[] = "nomfuncionario LIKE '$nomfuncionario'";
   if( !empty( $datcadastro ) ) $WHERE[] = "DATE_FORMAT(datcadastro,...) = '$datcadastro'";


   $query = 'SELECT  FROM ';
   if( !empty($WHERE) ) $query .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $WHERE );  mas obrigado por tudo .

Comment: @allan não se esqueça dos campos e do nome da tabela na $query inicial

Comment: @Bacco fiz da sua forma , mas não funcionou , da forma que eu fiz tá funcionando quase tudo , a única coisa que faz é quando deixo o campo da data em branco e preencho o nome ele ainda vem tudo o que era pra vim só o nome que coloquei .

Comment: Lincoln, formatei sua resposta e tirei os espaços a mais, veja se está correto o ajuste.